# Crop and Extend Heigth of Thumbnail if new Heigth is below X

Tags: imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I'm currently trying to achieve the following:

1. Create Thumbnail if picture exceeds the thumbnail size limit
2. If the generated thumbnail is wider than W, crop it to W (taking the center part)
3. If the heigth of the picture at that point (original or resized by 1.) is smaller than H, increase the heigth to H and fill it with color/transparency. Do not resize the image, just fill up the empty space

Part 3 is giving me trouble. What I currently have is the following

```
gm convert img.jpg -thumbnail 'x300>' -gravity
Center -background skyblue -crop '600x300+0+0' -extent x300 -strip thumbnail.jpg
```

But the extend results in an increase of the width. Is there a command to achieve what I want?

Example Image (356x200):

[image: Start Image]

Current Result (534x300):

[image: Thumbnail]

Expected (356x300):

[image: Excpected]

Thumbnails wider than 600px should be cropped to max 600 width. So I think what I need is `gm convert img.jpg -thumbnail '600x300>' -background skyblue -gravity center -extent {{current_width}}x300 -strip thumbnail.jpg`. But I think it's not build in functionality?

Comment: You have only specified on dimension to test x300. You should not need the crop as the -extent will crop if needed. So as a guess `- -thumbnail 600x300> -gravity center -background skyblue -extend 600x300 -strip jpg:-`  Please provide an example input and output, so we can see actually what you are trying to do.

Comment: @fmw42 I've updated the description. I think what I need is -extent {{current_width}}x300. Is there a way for that?

Comment: In IM 7 `magick image ... -extent "%wx300" ...`  In IM 6, you would have to split your command into two parts and get the current width separately and put into a variable. Then use the variable as `-extent ${current_width}x300.

Comment: @fmw42 Feel free to post that as an answer. I went the custom way with precalculating the thumbnail width